# RadWindow in default title as the targeted page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup, telerik, radwindow

In javascript : `Window.Open`, if `_blank` is used, the pop up window will be titled as the targeted page's title, How to achieve that for `RadWindow`?
I have tried the following but it didn't work:

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function windowLoad(oWindow, args) {
            oWindow.set_title(oWindow.argument);
            return false;
        }

        function OpenWindow(u) {
            var oWindow = radopen(u, "SideAdWindow");
            oWindow.argument = '_blank';
            oWindow.remove_pageLoad(windowLoad);
            oWindow.add_pageLoad(windowLoad);

            return false;

        }
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use its set_title("RadWIndow title") method: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-radwindow-methods.html.

```
        var oWindow = radopen(u, "SideAdWindow");
        oWindow.set_title(document.title);
```